# Display Loading GIF on page load - Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am loading an IFrame containing a page with a long list of dynamic data into a site.  It takes a few seconds to load depending on the broadband speed and needs to be iframed due to the setup.

I would like to show a loading GIF so the user knows something is happening, but I'm struggling to make it appear as a background image in either the parent page container or the div surrounding the content within the iframed page.

Comment: please paste your code how you are using GIF image ..

Answer (score 0):

You could add the image as a background of the `body` element inside the iframe, with a position near at the top and centered. E.g. `background-position: center 30px`

When table rendering starts, the image will be overlapped, so it's not even necessary to remove it via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>

<script>
    var foo = function(){
      var a = document.getElementById('content');
      var b = document.getElementById('loading_img');
      a.style.top='';
      a.style.left='';
      a.style.position='';
      b.style.display='none';
    };
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="foo();">
    <img id="loading_img" style="display:block;margin:20px auto;" src="loading.gif" />
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute;left:-8000px;top:-20000px;">
    .. table .. and stuff
    </div>
    </body>
```

not tested, but should work :)